# Linking Django project to existing MySQL database in EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I've created an android app who's backend is stored in a AWS EC2 instance. I am now creating a website using Django and I would like them to share the same database, is this possible, if so how?

I've been looking for the whole day and can't seem to find a solution, I've looked into deploying a Django application on AWS and it seems like I have to use Elastic Beanstalk which creates another EC2 instance and there doesn't seem to be a way to link it to my existing one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely share the same database - and there is no requirement to have second ec2 instance, but you haven't given enough specifics about how you are setup to know what issues you are having.

Also, you don't need to use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy an app, that is just one of many ways.

You can RDP or SSH into your ec2 instance and just copy in the files you need and configure the server - just like you would on any server that wasn't in AWS.

Comment: I'm glad to hear, I'll try and SSH into it as I'm more confortable with that, thanks